# Exporting Java Documentation to XML

Tags: java, xml, perl, documentation, java-7

I'm looking to export the [Java SE 7 Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) from HTML into parse-able XML.

Whether this is done with a scripting language like Perl, or done directly from Java (maybe with Eclipse), I'm open to suggestions. Perhaps someone has already done it?

I need most of the data available in the API's Javadoc, so it would take an eternity to do it manually. I'm not looking for code, I could figure that out myself, I'm just looking for some ideas on doing this, as I'm sure there's an "easy" way, and I don't want to waste too much time doing it one way and later finding out I can do it quicker in another.

Not that it should matter, but I will be reading the XML with C#.

I know it's a bit of a strange question, but I don't know where else to ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go: [Javadoc as XML](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipjdoc/index.html)

If you have the JDK installed, complete source code, to extract the Javadoc is found in `<your JDK folder>\src.zip`

Comment: I thought this would be possible! Thanks, you saved me a lot of Perl scraping!

Comment: Ok, finished converting to XML... The `-multiple` command line option doesn't function correctly, in that instead of each Class being in it's own file, each class gets it's own file, but the previous classes are still stored in them. E.g. File1: `Class 1`, File2: `Class1 Class2`, File3: `Class1 Class2 Class3`, etc. So don't use that feature, anyone who is trying to do the same.